# Express.js JWT Axios : Request Set-Cookie not sending after redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, jwt

I'm using httponly cookie for JWT joken for API authentication, Initial login I am able to receive Set-Cookie Token after redirection request header doesn't have cookie in that request. Hence I am unable to validate the token.

After login validation, I am sending httponly cookie with JWT token and some data(for local storage) to client browser.

```
 res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: false });
 res.status(200).send(data);
```

After localStorage.setItem("","") in client side, I am redirecting to different page using  window.location.href = "/dashboard.html" onload of the page trying to call axios request to express server. but cookies has not sending as part of request header.

The Configuration and troubleshooting followed:

- withCredentials in ClientSide default axios configuration.

  **axios.defaults.withCredentials = true**
- express ServerSide Configuration.

  **app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:8000");
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
      next();
    });**
- cros origin

  **cors({credentials: true,""});**
- cookie parser

  **app.use(cookieParser());**

Checked the res.redirection(302,"http://localhost:8000/dashboard.html") not working. Please check the image for more reference.

[Inital Login Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io4aY.jpg)
[After Redirect Request Header not having cokkie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql7RH.png)

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: you should set { httpOnly: true, sameSite: "None", secure: true }